# c++ Lithuanian language, how to get more than ascii

Tags: c++, character-encoding, locale

I am trying to use Lithuanian in my c++ application, but every try is unsuccesfull.

Multi-byte character set is used. I have tryed everything i have tought of, i am new in c++. Never ever tryed to do something in Lithuanian.

Tryed every `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8"); setlocale(LC_ALL, "Lithuanian");`...

Researched for 2 hours and didnt found proper examples, solution.

I do have a average sized project which needs Lithuanian translation from database and it cant understand most of "ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪąčęėįšųū".

Compiler - "Visual studio 2013"
Database - sqlite3.

I cant get simple strings to work(defined myself), and output as Lithuanian to win32 application, even.

Comment: Encoding handling of source files is compiler dependent, you have to tell us which compiler you're using if you want your source files to use a multi-byte character set.

Comment: How is the text encoded in the database? Is it Unicode, or is it ISO 8859? It might be ISO 8859, that's the old Windows pre-Unicode character set for Lithuanian.

Comment: Compiler - "Visual studio 2013" Database - sqlite, last version.

I cant get simple strings to work, and output as Lithuanian to win32 application, even.

Comment: I repeat the question - is the text encoding ISO 8859 or not?

Comment: Have you problems with *win32 console* or plain *win32* ? Is the problem about displaying the caracters or setting the locale without triggering an exception ? Or mismatches between what's stored in database and in memory ?

Comment: i have no idea what is the encoding of sqlite database. the sources says - 
SQLite3 uses UTF-8 by default. UTF-16 is supported by the database engine

i have an option to use ur mentioned encoding - 

SQLite supports ISO-8859-1 (the default) and UTF-8 as a compile-time option. If you install a binary package, it most likely uses ISO-8859-1.

Comment: database is fine(everything is in Lithuanian there), i cant get the data from the database and display it as Lithuanian. it fails on first attempt to initialize a string with data from database, and callback function of sqlite already shows nonLithuanian characters(when paused on callback). my solution just hates utf8, i guess. plain win32 dialog application.

Comment: Show code that fails, actual results of its run, and desired results. These things are called data. Absent data, we are having a pleasant empty talk about nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows use wide character strings (<sup>1</sup>UTF-16 encoding, `wchar_t` type) for internal text handling, and preferably UTF-8 for external text files and networking.

Note that Visual C++ will translate narrow text literals from the source encoding to Windows ANSI, which is a platform-dependent usually single-byte encoding (you can check which one via the `GetACP` API function), i.e., Visual C++ has the platform-specific Windows ANSI as its narrow C++ execution character set.

But also do note that for an app restricted to non-Windows platforms, i.e. Unix-land, it makes practical sense to do everything in UTF-8, based on `char` type.

---

For the database communication you may need to translate to and from the program's internal text representation.

This depends on what the database interface requires, which is not stated.

---

Example for console output in Windows:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

auto main() -> int
{
    _setmode( _fileno( stdout ), _O_WTEXT );

    using namespace std;
    wcout << L"ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪąčęėįšųū" << endl;
}
```

To make this compile by default with g++, the source code encoding needs to be UTF-8. Then, to make it produce correct results with Visual C++ the source code encoding needs to be UTF-8 *with BOM*, which happily is also accepted by modern versions of g++. For otherwise the Visual C++ compiler will assume the Windows ANSI encoding and produce an incorrect UTF-16 string.

Not coincidentally this is the default meaning of **UTF-8** in Windows, e.g. in the Notepad editor, namely UTF-8 with BOM.

But note that while in Windows the problem is that the main system compiler *requires* a BOM for UTF-8, in Unix-land the problem is the opposite, that many old tools *can't handle* the BOM (for example, even MinGW g++ 4.9.1 isn't yet entirely up to speed: it sometimes includes the BOM bytes, then incorrectly interpreted, in error messages).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>) On other platforms wide character text can be encoded in other ways, e.g. with UTF-32. In fact the Windows convention is in direct conflict with the C and C++ standards which require that a single `wchar_t` should be able to encode any character in the extended character set. However, this requirement was, AFAIK, imposed after Windows adopted UTF-16, so the fault probably lies with the politics of the C and C++ standardization process, not yet another Microsoft'ism.</sup>

Comment: FYI this **does not work** on my Windows 8 machine and on my Windows server 2008 R2 machine.

Comment: Teach me. I have 30 years of experience as a programmer. I teach people Unix, C++ and (yes) Unicode. I am not able to make this crap work no matter what I try. `cl yourfile.cpp && .\yourfile`. Runs VS 10.0, compiles without errors, displays garbage instead of Lithuanian characters. Font set to Lucida Console. Where is my error?

Comment: @n.m. Difficult to remote-diagnose, but I would guess some crappy source file encoding, such as UTF-8 without BOM. And yes, I agree that the Microsoft runtime support for Unicode is, as you so eloquently put it, crappy. It's what we just have to deal with.

Comment: @n.m. By the way, I generally use this string in i18n examples: "Norwegian blåbærsyltetøy pleases a 日本国 кошка…" (Norwegian blueberry jam pleases a Japanese cat). One does not expect the Chinese glyphs to be correctly *presented* in a console in a Western country, but they should be correctly copied back from the console to e.g. Word.

Comment: Wow. You are right. Why the heck would BOM be needed here? Microsoft is truly puzzling. "Use of a BOM is neither required nor recommended for UTF-8" --- the Unicode standard.

Comment: @n.m. All I know is that for one old version of Visual C++ there was a patch that made it default to UTF-8 encoding for source code. But no longer. Now it determines the source encoding from the contents, defaulting to Windows ANSI, but UTF-8 if there is an UTF-8 BOM, and UTF-16 if it finds zero-bytes (at least when it finds those consistently, I'm not sure how reliable its detection is).

Answer (score 0):

**Complexity of internationalisation**

There are several related but distinct topics that can cause mismatches between them, making try and error approach very tedious:

- **type** used for storing strings and chars:  windows iuses `wchar_t` by default, but for most APIs you have also `char` equivalents functions
- **character set encoding** this defines how the chars stored in the type are to be understood. For exemple unicode (UTF8, UTF16, UTF32), 7 bits ascii, 8 bit ansii. In [windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), by default it is UTF16 for `wchar_t` and ansi/windows for `char`
- **locale** defines, among other things, the character set asumptions, when processing strings.  This permit to use language independent functions  like `isalpha(i, loc)`, `islower(i, loc)`,   `ispunct(i, loc)` to find out if a given character is alphanumeric, a lower case alphabetic, or a punctuation, for example to bereak down a user text into words. C++ offers here portable functions.
- **output codepage** or **font** used to show a character to the user. This assumes that the [font used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183415%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shows the characters using the same character set used in the code internals.
- **source code** encoding.  For example your editor could assume an ansi encoding, with windows 1252 character set.

**Most typical errors**

The problem n°1 is Win32 console output, as unicode is not well supported by the console. But this is not your problem here.

Another cause of mismatch is the encoding of your **text editor**.  It might not be unicode, but use a windows code page.  In this case, you type "Č", the deditor displays it as such, but editor might use [windows 1257](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305150.aspx) encoding for lithuanian and store 0xC8 in the file.  If you then display this literal with a windows unicode function, it will interpret 0xC8 as "latin E grave accent" and print something else, as the right unicode encoding for "Č" is 0x010C !

I can be even worse:  the compiler may have its own assumption about character set encoding used and convert your litterals into unicode using false assumptions  (it happened to me when I used some exotic code generation switch).

**How to do ?**

To figure out what goes wront, proceed by elimination:

- First, for plain windows, use the native unicode setting.  Ok it's UTF16 and wchar_t instead of UTF8 and as thus comes with [some drawbacks](http://utf8everywhere.org/), but it's native and well supported.
- Then use explict unicode coding in litterals, for example `TEXT("\u010C")`  instead of `TEXT("Č")`.  This avoids editor and compiler mismatch.
- If it's still not the right character, make sure that your font FULLY supports unicode.  The default system font for instance doesn't while most other do.  You can easily check with the windows font pannel (WindowKey+R fonts then click on "search char")  to display the character table of your font.
- Set fonts explicitely in your code

For example, a very tiny experiment :

```
...
case WM_PAINT:
{
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    auto hf = CreateFont(24, 0, 0, 0, 0, TRUE, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, L"Times New Roman");
    auto hfOld = SelectObject(hdc, hf); // if you comment this out, € and Č won't display
    TextOut(hdc, 50, 50, L"Test with éç € \u010C special chars", 30);
    SelectObject(hdc, hfOld);
    DeleteObject(hf);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
}
```